# In Java, how do I call a base class's method from the overriding method in a derived class?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, polymorphism

I have two Java classes: B, which extends another class A, as follows :

```
class A {
    public void myMethod() { /* ... */ }
}

class B extends A {
    public void myMethod() { /* Another code */ }
}
```

I would like to call the `A.myMethod()` from `B.myMethod()`. I am coming from the [C++ world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357307/how-to-call-a-parent-class-function-from-derived-class-function), and I don't know how to do this basic thing in Java.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

The keyword you're looking for is `super`. See [this guide](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html), for instance.

Comment: Looks like in C++ you can call a specific ancestor method, but not java, you can just pass it up the chain...

Answer (score 146):

Just call it using super.

```
public void myMethod()
{
    // B stuff
    super.myMethod();
    // B stuff
}
```

Answer (score 21):

`super.MyMethod()` should be called inside the `MyMethod()` of the `class B`. So it should be as follows

```
class A {
    public void myMethod() { /* ... */ }
}

class B extends A {
    public void myMethod() { 
        super.MyMethod();
        /* Another code */ 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Answer is as follows:

```
super.Mymethod();
super();                // calls base class Superclass constructor.
super(parameter list);          // calls base class parameterized constructor.
super.method();         // calls base class method.
```

Answer (score 8):

call super.myMethod();

Answer (score 7):

I am pretty sure that you can do it using Java Reflection mechanism. It is not as straightforward as using super but it gives you more power.

```
class A
{
    public void myMethod()
    { /* ... */ }
}

class B extends A
{
    public void myMethod()
    {
        super.myMethod(); // calling parent method
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't show any java reflection in the code and is the same code as the others. Is there more to the answer?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [super](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) keyword.

Answer (score 4):

```
super.baseMethod(params);
```

call the base methods with **super** keyword and pass the respective params.

Answer (score 3):

```
class test
{
    void message()
    {
        System.out.println("super class");
    }
}

class demo extends test
{
    int z;
    demo(int y)
    {
        super.message();
        z=y;
        System.out.println("re:"+z);
    }
}
class free{
    public static void main(String ar[]){
        demo d=new demo(6);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

See, here you are overriding one of the method of the base class hence if you like to call base class method from inherited class then you have to use ***super*** keyword in the same method of the inherited class.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Using super keyword access parent class variable
class test {
    int is,xs;

    test(int i,int x) {
        is=i;
        xs=x;
        System.out.println("super class:");
    }
}

class demo extends test {
    int z;

    demo(int i,int x,int y) {
        super(i,x);
        z=y;
        System.out.println("re:"+is);
        System.out.println("re:"+xs);
        System.out.println("re:"+z);
    }
}

class free{
    public static void main(String ar[]){
        demo d=new demo(4,5,6);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If u r using these methods for initialization then use constructors of class A and pass super keyword inside the constructor of class B.

Or if  you want to call a method of super class from the subclass method then you have to use super keyword inside the subclass method  like : 
super.myMethod();