# Is there a way to call an object's base class method that's overriden? (C++)

Tags: c++, oop

I know some languages allow this. Is it possible in C++?

Comment: Do you mean a) from within the derived class or b) from a function not in the related classes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: How to call a parent class function from derived class function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357307/c-how-to-call-a-parent-class-function-from-derived-class-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes:

```
#include <iostream>

class X
{
    public:
        void T()
        {
            std::cout << "1\n";
        }
};

class Y: public X
{
    public:
        void T()
        {
            std::cout << "2\n";
            X::T();             // Call base class.
        }
};


int main()
{
    Y   y;
    y.T();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class A
{
  virtual void foo() {}
};

class B : public A
{
   virtual void foo()
   {
     A::foo();
   }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just specify the type of the base class.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base
{
    void func() { std::cout << "Base::func\n"; }
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    void func() { std::cout << "Derived::func\n"; Base::func(); }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.func();
}
```