# how to call base class method from derive class in c++?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to call an object's base class method that's overriden? (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619769/is-there-a-way-to-call-an-objects-base-class-method-thats-overriden-c)

First question is calling super() constructor in java same as initializing the super class constructor first in c++ like.

```
sub() : super(){}
```

is there a way to call super class method in c++ like in java

ex.

```
public sub(){
super.someMethod();
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: How to call a parent class function from derived class function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/357307/), [Is there a way to call an object's base class method that's overriden? (C++)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1619769/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To call the base constructor of a class, you call it as `BaseClassName(args)`. For example:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() { }
    virtual void Foo() { std::cout << "A's foo" << std::endl; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() : A() { }
    void Foo();
};
```

To  call the base class version of a method, you do `BaseClassName::MethodName`:

```
void B::Foo()
{
    std::cout << "B's foo" << std::endl;
    A::Foo();
}
```