# Call base class method from derived class object

Tags: c++, inheritance

How can I call a base class method which is overridden by the derived class, from a derived class object?

```
class Base{
  public:
    void foo(){cout<<"base";}
};

class Derived:public Base{
  public:
    void foo(){cout<<"derived";}
}

int main(){
  Derived bar;
  //call Base::foo() from bar here?
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2437586/951890

Comment: It's not overridden if it's not virtual, `Derived::foo` rather _hides_ `Base::foo`.

Comment: This looks very much like a design problem. If `Derived` has its own version of `foo`, chances are it was **not** designed to behave correctly if someone outside the class calls the base version instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a parent class function from derived class function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/357307/608639)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can always(*) refer to a base class's function by using a *qualified-id*:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base{
  public:
    void foo(){std::cout<<"base";}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  public:
    void foo(){std::cout<<"derived";}
};

int main()
{
  Derived bar;
  //call Base::foo() from bar here?
  bar.Base::foo(); // using a qualified-id
  return 0;
}
```

[Also fixed some typos of the OP.]

(*) Access restrictions still apply, and base classes can be ambiguous.

---

If `Base::foo` is not `virtual`, then `Derived::foo` does not *override* `Base::foo`. Rather, `Derived::foo` *hides* `Base::foo`. The difference can be seen in the following example:

```
struct Base {
   void foo()         { std::cout << "Base::foo\n"; }
   virtual void bar() { std::cout << "Base::bar\n"; }
};

struct Derived : Base {
   void foo()         { std::cout << "Derived::foo\n"; }
   virtual void bar() { std::cout << "Derived::bar\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    Base* b = &d;
    b->foo(); // calls Base::foo
    b->bar(); // calls Derived::bar
}
```

(`Derived::bar` is implicitly virtual even if you don't use the `virtual` keyword, as long as it's signature is compatible to `Base::bar`.)

A *qualified-id* is either of the form `X :: Y` or just `:: Y`. The part before the `::` specifies where we want to look up the identifier `Y`. In the first form, we look up `X`, then we look up `Y` *from within `X`'s context.* In the second form, we look up `Y` in the global namespace.

An *unqualified-id* does not contain a `::`, and therefore does not (itself) specify a context where to look up the name.

In an expression `b->foo`, both `b` and `foo` are *unqualified-ids*. `b` is looked up in the current context (which in the example above is the `main` function). We find the local variable `Base* b`. Because `b->foo` has the form of a class member access, we look up `foo` from the context of the type of `b` (or rather `*b`). So we look up `foo` from the context of `Base`. We will find the member function `void foo()` declared inside `Base`, which I'll refer to as `Base::foo`.

For `foo`, we're done now, and call `Base::foo`.

For `b->bar`, we first find `Base::bar`, but it is declared `virtual`. Because it is `virtual`, we perform a *virtual dispatch*. This will call the final function overrider in the class hierarchy of the type of the object `b` points to. Because `b` points to an object of type `Derived`, the final overrider is `Derived::bar`.

When looking up the name `foo` from `Derived`'s context, we will find `Derived::foo`. This is why `Derived::foo` is said to *hide* `Base::foo`. Expressions such as `d.foo()` or, inside a member function of `Derived`, using simply `foo()` or `this->foo()`, will look up from the context of `Derived`.

When using a *qualified-id*, we explicitly state the context of where to look up a name. The expression `Base::foo` states that we want to look up the name `foo` from the context of `Base` (it can find functions that `Base` inherited, for example). **Additionally, it disables virtual dispatch.**

Therefore, `d.Base::foo()` will find `Base::foo` and call it; `d.Base::bar()` will find `Base::bar` and call it.

---

Fun fact: Pure virtual functions can have an implementation. They cannot be called via virtual dispatch, because they *need* to be overridden. However, you can still call their implementation (if they have one) by using a *qualified-id*.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

void Base::foo() { std::cout << "look ma, I'm pure virtual!\n"; }

struct Derived : Base {
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "Derived::foo\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    d.foo();       // calls Derived::foo
    d.Base::foo(); // calls Base::foo
}
```

---

Note that *access-specifiers* both of class members and base classes have an influence on whether or not you can use a qualified-id to **call** a base class's function on an object of a derived type.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
public:
    void public_fun() { std::cout << "Base::public_fun\n"; }
private:
    void private_fun() { std::cout << "Base::private_fun\n"; }
};

struct Public_derived : public Base {
public:
    void public_fun() { std::cout << "Public_derived::public_fun\n"; }
    void private_fun() { std::cout << "Public_derived::private_fun\n"; }
};

struct Private_derived : private Base {
public:
    void public_fun() { std::cout << "Private_derived::public_fun\n"; }
    void private_fun() { std::cout << "Private_derived::private_fun\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Public_derived p;
    p.public_fun();        // allowed, calls Public_derived::public_fun
    p.private_fun();       // allowed, calls Public_derived::public_fun
    p.Base::public_fun();  // allowed, calls Base::public_fun
    p.Base::private_fun(); // NOT allowed, tries to name Base::public_fun

    Private_derived r;
    r.Base::public_fun();  // NOT allowed, tries to call Base::public_fun
    r.Base::private_fun(); // NOT allowed, tries to name Base::private_fun
}
```

Accessibility is orthogonal to name lookup. So name hiding does not have an influence on it (you can leave out `public_fun` and `private_fun` in the derived classes and get the same behaviour and errors for the qualified-id calls).

The error in `p.Base::private_fun()` is different from the error in `r.Base::public_fun()` by the way: The first one already fails to refer to the name `Base::private_fun` (because it's a private name). The second one fails to convert `r` from `Private_derived&` to `Base&` for the `this`-pointer (essentially). This is why the second one works from within `Private_derived` or a friend of `Private_derived`.

Comment: Your derived class foo hides base class foo. Does using a qualifier-id syntax in this case also works ?

Comment: @nurabha Could you elaborate, please? I don't quite understand what your question is.

Comment: Actually base class foo is not overriden by derived class foo but it is hidden. if you point a base class pointer to derived object and make a call using this pointer to foo, base will be printed.   Base* basePtrToDerived = &bar;  basePtrToDerived->foo();

Comment: @nurabha Yes. Casting to base is another way to call `Base::foo`. Using a qualified-id to call a base class' function works irrespectively of what happens to that function in the derived class - it can be hidden, it can be overridden, it can be made private (by using a using-declaration), you're directly accessing the base class' function when using a qualified-id.

Answer (score 22):

First of all Derived should inherit from Base.

```
 class Derived : public Base{
```

That said

First of you can just not have foo in Derived

```
class Base{
  public:
    void foo(){cout<<"base";}
};

class Derived : public Base{

}

int main(){
  Derived bar;
  bar.foo() // calls Base::foo()
  return 0;
}
```

Second you can make Derived::foo call Base::foo.

```
class Base{
  public:
    void foo(){cout<<"base";}
};

class Derived : public Base{
  public:
    void foo(){ Base::foo(); }
                ^^^^^^^^^^
}

int main(){
  Derived bar;
  bar.foo() // calls Base::foo()
  return 0;
}
```

Third you can use qualified id of Base::foo

```
 int main(){
    Derived bar;
    bar.Base::foo(); // calls Base::foo()
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I find this answer way more helpful than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Consider making `foo()` virtual in the first place.

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;

    virtual void foo() { … }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    virtual void foo() override { … }
};
```

However, this does the job:

```
int main() {
    Derived bar;
    bar.Base::foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would probably be better to write it as `bar.Base::foo()`

Comment: @Mankarse TIL that is possible.

Comment: If you make foo() virtual, still need to call `bar.Base::foo();` to access the base class method right?

Comment: @XunYang yes, you do. Virtuality is irrelevant in this situation, but I found it worth mentioning.

Comment: OK thanks! Actually I'm using a bunch of libraries that use a very generic function name `void Base1::begin(){\\initialization}`, `class Derived:public Base1, public Base2{...}; void Derived::begin(){\\initialization}`, so the architectural is sadly out of my reach :(
And just trying to do a hackish test here :)

Comment: virtual keyword used in your derived class is redundant

Answer (score 0):

**An important [additional] note**: you will still have compilation errors if ***Name Hiding*** occurs.

In this case, either utilize the using keyword, or use the qualifer. Additionally, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16837660/786356) as well.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base{
  public:
    void foo(bool bOne, bool bTwo){std::cout<<"base"<<bOne<<bTwo;}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  public:
    void foo(bool bOne){std::cout<<"derived"<<bOne;}
};

int main()
{
  Derived bar;
  //bar.foo(true,true);      // error:    derived func attempted
  bar.foo(true);             // no error: derived func
  bar.Base::foo(true,true);  // no error: base func, qualified
  return 0;
}
```