# Confusion about the phenomenon of overriding

Tags: c++, overriding

I am little confused about when to say that function is overriden.

> My book says "When a derived class creates a function with the same return type and signature as a
> member function in the base class, but with a new implementation, it is said to be overriding
> that function."

I am clear what book saying but my question is if I only kept the name same and changed the return type and signature, can I say that function is overriden or is there any different term for it?
Like I tried the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 class Mammal
{
 public:
  int Move() const  
   { 
    cout << "mammal moving\n"; 
    return 1; 
   }
   
  void Move(int x) const 
   {
    cout << "walked " << x << " steps\n"; 
   }
};
  
 class Dog : public Mammal
{
 public:
  void Move()
  { 
   cout << "Dog moving\n";
  }
};
  
 int main()
{
 Dog Moti;
 Moti.Move();
//Moti.Move(2);  error: no matching function for call to 'Dog::Move(int)'
 cout << endl;
 return 0; 
}
```

> Output : Dog moving

So I have Move() method in `Dog` but it's return type and signature is different than Move() method in `Mammal`. So is it correct to say Move() in `Dog` has overridden Move() in `Mammal`. Why I got this confusion is because when I called `Moti.Move(2)`, I received error. This means `void Move(int x) const` in `Mammal` got hidden. But phenomenon of 'hiding' occurs when one of the overloaded methods in base class is overridden in derived class. So that's why I think "Move() in Dog has overridden Move() in Mammal" but according to book definition it seems wrong.

I did some internet search where I found that "in case of virtual functions, return type must be same or covarient" but my question is not about virtual functions or anything. I am just confused about can I say overriding has occurred in the above code or is there any different term for it.

Comment: You can only `override` a virtual function. The term used for what you have done is shadowing or hiding.

Comment: Providing a function with the same name and different signature is overloading.   If that is done in a derived class (same name as a function in the base class, but different signature) the version in the derived class also hides the base version.

Comment: What book are you using?  You can call the other Move method using `Moti.Mammal::Move(2);`.

Comment: Teach yourself c++ in 21 days by Jesse Liberty (p.n 385)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in above code reminds me a very interesting concept of CPP, **Name Hiding** which simply states that, if we try to overload a method in a derived class, then the compiler will hide the base class method unless we explicitly informs the compiler to include a base class method or we explicitly call the base class method using scope resolution operator like `Moti.Mammal::Move(2);`

Do Checkout some related articles:

https://bastian.rieck.me/blog/posts/2016/name_hiding_cxx/

[overloading base class method in derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835897/overloading-base-class-method-in-derived-class)

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-89/

P.S: we can't overload methods based on return types, if we try to do so there will be an error.