# How to call base class virtual function in C++

Tags: c++

Suppose I have two classes class `A` and class `B`, class `B` is derived from class `A` `public`. Here class `A` have `virtual emp()`,and class `B` have `emp()`,
In this case how can I call base class virtual function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call base class method from derived class object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853031/call-base-class-method-from-derived-class-object)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can invoke `A::emp()` directly

```
B* obj = new B();
b->A::emp();
```

Or within a method of A or B.

```
void B::SomeOtherMethod()
{
     A::emp(); // same as this->A::emp();
}
```

Comment: @Krishna - Welcome to Stack Overflow. If the answer works for you, don't forget to "accept" it.