# Is that possible in python?

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance

In c++ the object of derived class can access method of base class like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853031/call-base-class-method-from-derived-class-object).

```
class a:
    def save(self):
        print('a executed')


class b(a):
    def save(self):
        print('b executed')


class c(a):
    def save(self):
        print('c executed')


class d(b, c):
    def save(self):
        print('d executed')


obj = d()
```

Is this possible in python that `obj` of class `d` can access the method of class `c`. I'm not discussing about use of `super()`. 
e.g.,
if some syntax like this

```
obj.c.save() #not correct its just my thinking
```

then output should be:

```
c executed
```

Comment: That would simply be `c.save(obj)`.

Comment: @jashonharper I think you mean `c.save(self)`.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanx it solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python you should use `super` or do something like this:

```
c.save(obj)
```