# Is there a way to call an object's overridden base class methods?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overriding, c++17

Given a pointer to a derived object, which has overridden some method `virtual void moo()`, is there a way to call the base's `moo()` method?

One way is to create a sliced base class object from the derived object, but that would involve copying:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A {
    public: virtual void moo() { std::cout << "moo from A\n"; }
};

class B final : public A {
    public: void moo() override final { std::cout << "moo from B\n"; };
};

int main() {
    A* a_ptr = new B; // could point to any A or A-derived object.

    A a(*a_ptr); // is there a way to get A::moo without doing this?
    a.moo(); // moo from A of course, but would be cooler without the copy above
}
```

Why would I wanna do that you ask?

*So glad that you ask... not, because now I have to explain everything to you. Well A's `virtual void moo()` is actually more like `std::string serialize()`, which gives A's data members serialized into a `std::string`. Now when you have a big `std::vector<A*>` pointing to all sorts of derived objects and only the data from the base objects are needed (to be sent over network), it'd be nice to get only `A::moo`s, although those pointers in that vector point to all sorts of moos.*

*(I'm aware of the possibility to 'simply' put a second `void moo2()` into A, that does not get overridden. But I'd also like to know if there's a third or fourth alternative.)*

Comment: @TheUndeadFish Using the namespace resolve thing - No that's only possible from inside the derived object.

Comment: `a_ptr->A::moo();`.

Comment: @songyuanyao Really? I was not aware of that.

Comment: If you wants to call base class' overridden function using derived class' object then here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15853092/1468487)

Comment: @nada The syntax was shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6319619/5538420) under the linked question.

Comment: Or another if you prefer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853031/call-base-class-method-from-derived-class-object (note that googling "c++ call base class method" led me to these pretty fast).

Comment: @TheUndeadFish I'm duckduckgoing, and that led to nothing. Wouldn't get back to googling though. And yes that last question includes the needed syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can by using the calling syntax used when calling member function pointers.

```cpp
(a_ptr->A::moo)();
```

Or by simply stating where the function comes from (which scope it contains; from which parent class).

```cpp
a_ptr->A::moo();
```