# How to reuse table that would be based on different types in C++?

Tags: c++

I have problems to re-use parts of C++ code.

I need to register a number of objects in a table with the following code:

```
typedef map<ResourceType_t, GeneralResource*>   ResourceTable_t;
ResourceTable_t m_resourceTable;

template<class _Ty1,
class _Ty2> inline
pair<_Ty1, _Ty2> make_pair(_Ty1 _Val1, _Ty2 _Val2)
{   // return pair composed from arguments
return (pair<_Ty1, _Ty2>(_Val1, _Val2));
}


void MainModule::registerResource(ResourceType_t type, GeneralResource* pGeneral)
{
m_resourceTable.insert(make_pair(type, pGeneral)); 
}
```

However, for my new case, I need to fill the table with ojbects of type SpecificResource. How can I approach this new situation while still making use of m_resourceTable?

---

EDIT:

The strategy of inheritance seems to work, however, a new issue pops up:

```
class DifferentResource : 
              public GeneralDifferentResource, 
              public SpecificResource
```

GeneralDifferentResource inherites from GeneralResource. Now, we have some methods result into ambigious access problems. How to let DifferentResource first resolve methods from GeneralDifferentResource and second from SpecificResource (to resolve ambiguity) ?
How ambiguity can be resolved is explained here: [StackOverflow Question on Ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357307/c-how-to-call-a-parent-class-function-from-derived-class-function)

Comment: I edited your code. don't write `<pre>` tag when quoting code. Just use `{}` from the editor's menu.

Comment: Are you really defining make_pair yourself? If so, why?

Comment: make_pair is a given definition in the project... not sure either why it would have advantages...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, for my new case, I need to fill the table with objects of type SpecificResource.

Derive `SpecificResource` from `GeneralResource` and make it's destructor virtual:

```
class GeneralResource 
{
    virtual ~GeneralResource() {}
    //..
};

class SpecificResource : public GeneralResource 
{
   //...
};
```

---

If `GeneralResource` is not that general, then define an `AbstractResource` from which you can derive all other resource classes:

```
class AbstractResource
{
    virtual ~AbstractResource() {}
    //...  
};
class GeneralResource : public AbstractResource
{
    //..
};
class SpecificResource : public AbstractResource
{
   //...
};
```

And if you follow this approach, then use this map:

```
typedef map<ResourceType_t, AbstractResource*>   ResourceTable_t;
```

Comment: thanks for the example... it tried to define SpecificResource indeed... but without using inheritance... I will explore that path and let you know

Comment: hmm... ok... the compiler complains about "ambiguous" access to a method initForEnding() in a child of SpecificResource.

Comment: @poseid: how would I know without seeing the code? Why don't you post the code?

Comment: with strategy 1 (I think it is the "decorator" pattern), the compiler complains about "ambiguous" access to a method initForEnding() in a child of SpecificResource. I found this article explaining to make the inheritance virtual: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/87971-multiple-inheritance-in-c/ I will try ...

Answer (score 1):

Have SpecificResource inherit from GeneralResource, if it makes sense for you.