# Is it possible to "inherit" a derived function from a base class function?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Firstly, let me apologise for the title, I honestly couldn't think how to word it better.
The example below should make my question a little clearer:

```
class Foo    {
    public:
      Foo(int x);
    };

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
  Bar(int y) : Foo(y);
};
```

Demonstrates code that would force the Bar constructor to call the Foo constructor with parameter Y. My question is, is there a similar method for inheriting a derived class function to call a base class function?

For example all calls to `Bar.Func();` would also automatically call `Foo.Func();`?

Comment: This has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357307/c-how-to-call-a-parent-class-function-from-derived-class-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automatically, no. You can use `Base::member()` to call it, though.

```
struct foo {
    void frob() { std::cout << "foo::frob" << std::endl; }
};

struct bar : foo {
    void frob() { foo::frob(); std::cout << "bar::frob" << std::endl; }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo    {
    public:
      Foo(int x);
  void DoIt();
    };

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
  Bar(int y) : Foo(y);
  void DoIt();
};

void Bar::DoIt()
{
  Foo::DoIt();
}
```

If `Foo` is intended to be derived from and used polymorphicly, you should declare `DoIt` as `virtual`.  In addition, you will also want a `virtual` base class destructor.

Comment: I apologise I wasn't exactly clear on this, I'm currently solving my problem exactly as you suggested with a manual call in Bar::DoIt to Foo::DoIt. As with the constructor example in my question, is there a way to do this in the class interface similar to the constructor Bar(int y) : Foo(y) Say for example void DoIt() : Foo::DoIt() ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then no.  There is no initializer list for functions.  You must call the function explicitly in the body of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Any public function declared in `Foo` is also accessible via `Bar` (the same function will get called). If you may need to override the function in `Bar` to alter its behaviour, make it `virtual`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you'll need if you want to 'inherit' the function statements for a function F() from its base. Declare F() virtual in Foo, implement some statements there. Then declare F() in Bar and make a call to Foo::F() at the beginning of the implementation of Bar::F():

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo(int i) { cout << "Foo(" << i << ") called." << endl; }
  virtual void F() { cout << "foo::F() called." << endl; }

  virtual ~Foo() {};
};

class Bar : public Foo {
public:
  Bar(int i) : Foo(i) { cout << "Bar(" << i << ") called" << endl; }
  void F()  { Foo::F(); cout << "bar::F() called" << endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Bar b(3);
  b.F();
}
```

gives

Foo(3) called.
Bar(3) called 
foo::F() called.
bar::F() called