# how do I call a base class method from the derived class, if the derived class has a method with the same name?

Tags: c++

this is what I want to be able to do: (pseudo code)

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
    public Draw()
    {
        BaseClass.Draw()
    }
}

class BaseClass
{
    protected Draw();
}
```

Both draws have the same name and the same signature. The reason for wanting to do this is that sometimes I want my derived classes to have a draw function that simply calls the Base Classes draw, but at other times I want the derived class to choose when to call the base draw function or not. This meant that I can keep the class that I instantiate the derived classes in much cleaner, and can just call draw on all of them at all times. The derived classes themselves handle the nitty-gritty.

What exactly is the syntax for the `BaseClass.Draw` part? I thought you could actually just write that as it is, but the compiler is complaining, and it's not like I can just call `Draw` because the signatures are the same.

Comment: You shouldn't run programs as `sudo` unless you're totally sure you need to.

Comment: @kerrek, pretty sure `pseudo code` was meant.. and not sudo... :P

Comment: yes that's right, always thought it was sudo. My bad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: How to call a parent class function from derived class function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357307/c-how-to-call-a-parent-class-function-from-derived-class-function)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax is `BaseClass::Draw()`.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is

```
DeriveClass::Draw()
{
   BaseClass::Draw();
}
```