# is it possible to call a method in the base class from a derived class in c++?

Tags: c++

The base class is called Tree and it has a private function called insert inside it.

The derived class is called BST and it also has a private function called insert inside it, and I want this insert function to call the insert function inside the Tree class.

is this possible to do in C++ ?

Comment: Yes. How about googling the obvious and finding the answered questions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I call a base class method from the derived class, if the derived class has a method with the same name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358167/how-do-i-call-a-base-class-method-from-the-derived-class-if-the-derived-class-h)

Comment: You can't if it's private.

Comment: You can't call private member functions from outside the class, including from derived classes.  If you want Tree's `insert` function to be callable from derived classes, make it protected instead of private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot, unless the base class declares the derived class or its `insert()` member function to be one of its `friend`s.

The closest thing to what you want is to declare the base class `insert()` member function `protected`, rather than `private`. This would be simpler and more sensible.

Note that in general it isn't a good idea to give a derived class's member function the same name and signature as a member function in its base class, unless the base class member function is declared `virtual` and the derived class member function is meant to override it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer would be 'yes' if the insert method in the base class were `public` or `protected`. However, since you said it is `private`, the answer has to be 'no'.

Answer (score 1):

In a derived class you can call base class functions but only if they are `protected` or `public`. `private` methods can in general only be called by methods of the class itself.

There are however ugly hacks which make it possible to call private functions, see for example here: [Calling private method in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873138/calling-private-method-in-c) or [here](http://bloglitb.blogspot.de/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html) or [here](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm). A notable and not too hacky way could be a public member function which returns a pointer to the private function which you want to call.