# C++ extend inherited functions

Tags: c++

considering a simple inherited class:

```
class Base 
{
  void func() {
     cout << "base" << endl;
  }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  void func() {
      cout << "derived" << endl;
  } 
};
```

if I run Derived::func() I get

```
derived
```

I would like to modify this code to get

```
base
derived
```

Something more similar to an extension than an overriding.

I've been able to get something similar with constructors, but not with normal functions.

Many thanks, 
 Lucio

Comment: The same like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357307/c-how-to-call-a-parent-class-function-from-derived-class-function

Answer (score 28):

```
class Derived : public Base
{
  void func() {
      Base::func();   // Call the base method before doing our own.
      cout << "derived" << endl;
  } 
};
```

Answer (score 3):

To access the base-class function from the derived class, you can simply use:

```
Base::func();
```

In your case, you would have this as the first line of the derived implementation of `func()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Base::func();` is correct like a few others already stated.

Remember the constructor for the base class will always get called first, then the constructor for the derived class.

Answer (score 0):

You've talked about constructor, a derived class's constructor will call base class's one, no matter whether you use an inherited constructor,  it makes sense because a derived class should be able to construct the members inherited from the base class. And by default, constructor wouldn't be inherited.

**But, the "normal" method goes the much different way.**

First, please sure that in most of the time, it's not necessary for a method in derived class to call the same-name method in base class, and on the contrary, it will **cover** base class's one, although it did inherit it.

So if you really want to call base class one, you should tell complier explicitly. Using `baseclass::somemethod` will fulfill your request.

Comment: @bipll I think I understood your thought, I will edit it, thanks.

Answer (score -4):

You can't do so.
You'll have to do like

```
 Void derived:: func()
 {
  this->func(); /*you should use 'this pointer' to 
  access the base class functions*/
  cout<<"derived";
  }
```