# I want to extend dropEvent() (QListWidget), should I completely reimplement it?

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, implementation, qlistwidget

I have a QListWidget and I have set it to accept drops, the mode to be DragDrop etc and I can move QListWidgetItems all around the place (inside the QListWidget of course).

I like this behavior and I want it to let it as is, but I also want my QListWidget to accept drops from a QTreeWidget as well. If I attempt to reimplement the dropEvent() of my QListWidget then I lose the default behavior.

Is there any way to just extend the current behavior so as to have both drag-drop between listwidget items and drag-drop from the treewidget to the listwidget or I have to completely re-write both behaviors in my dropEvent() reimplementation?

Thanks a lot for any answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Subclass `QListWidget`, reimplement

```
virtual void    QListWidget::dropEvent ( QDropEvent * event )
```

and explicitly call

```
QListWidget::dropEvent(event);
```

whenever you need the default behavior.

[How to call a parent class function from derived class function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/357307/1122645)

Comment: Thanks both of you, how am I going to distinguish between the listwidget and the treewidget items, while both of them return application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist as mime type?

Answer (score 2):

Two ways:

1. implement a standalone [event filter](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters) and make it act upon `QEvent::Drop`. [Install it](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qobject.html#installEventFilter) on your original QListWidget. Return **false** so that the original `dropEvent()` handler is called afterwards.
2. inherit from `QListWidget`, reimplement `dropEvent(evt)` and as a last statement, call `QListWidget::dropEvent(evt);`. Your original behavior will be retained.

Comment: Thanks both of you, how am I going to distinguish between the listwidget and the treewidget items, while both of them return application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist as mime type?

Comment: QDropEvent->source()->inherits("QTreeWidget")