# how to call base class method from derived class method?

Tags: c++

```
class base
{
    int a, b;
public:
    bool valid();
    {
        bool ok = false;
        if (a > 5 && a < 10 && b > 2 && b < 8)
            ok = true;
            return ok;
    }
};

class derived : public base
{
    int a;
public:
    bool valid();
    {
        bool ok = false;
        if (a < 8 && a > 15 && // call base's class valid method;
            ok = true;
            return ok;
    }
};
```

Hpw to call base class valid method in derived class valid method?

Comment: Look up "scope resolution operator", aka `::`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357307/c-how-to-call-a-parent-class-function-from-derived-class-function

Comment: How could `a` be less than `8` *and* greater than `15`?

Comment: Though `a < 8 && a > 15` is already a rather strict condition.

Comment: Watch out, `derived` contains two subobjects named `a`!

Comment: also: bool valid(); <-- do you need that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class derived:public base
{

    int a;
    public:
        bool valid();
        {
              bool ok= false;
              if(a<8 && a>15 && base::valid()) //call base's class valid method;
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
                  side note: think about changing this condition
                             probably a>8 && a<15
                  ok = true; 
              return ok;

        }

};
```

Comment: haha are you kidding?  did you randomly paste base::valid()?

Comment: oh you fixed it :p good call.

Comment: (a<8) was random condition to show......any ways i got my answer thanks.... base::valid() worked

Answer (score 0):

Use `base::valid()` anywhere within the `derived` class code.