# Any way to avoid manual wrapping of methods of a base class to mark them Q_INVOKABLE?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm having a base class I derive from. That base class (`BaseClass`) is a pure c++ class (doesn't derive from QObject) and implements methods, which I'd like to provide to my QML interface without alteration.

Let's assume the base class implements a method `bool foobar()`. In my derived class (`DerivedClass`) I now wrap them like this:

DerivedClass.h:

```
class DerivedClass : public QObject, public Singleton<Phone>, public BaseClass {
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    Q_INVOKABLE bool qt_foobar();
```

DerivedClass.cpp:

```
bool DerivedClass::qt_foobar() {
    return DerivedClass::instance().foobar();
```

That works perfectly fine, however I'm wondering whether there's a more elegant way to just pass or declare respective methods as `Q_INVOKABLE` without that wrapping and renaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can at least avoid having different names by calling BaseCass's implementation explicitly ([as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357307/how-to-call-a-parent-class-function-from-derived-class-function)) and do so directly in the header:

```
class DerivedClass : public QObject, public Singleton<Phone>, public BaseClass
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        Q_INVOKABLE bool foobar() { return BaseClass::foobar() };
```

I never came across a way to register invokable methods to the MOC other than `Q_INVOKABLE` in front of a signature in a header.