# C++ - Calling overridden method in derived class from method base class

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Let `f1` be a virtual, non-abstract method of the class `c` and `f2` be a method of the class `c`.
Let also `c_derived` be the derived class from the base class `c`.
Assume that `f1` is overridden in `c_derived`. How can I call the method `f1` (overridden) of `c_derived`- from the method `f2` in `c`? 
 *Possible work-around.* Adding a function pointer parameter to the `c::f2` parameter list, creating a wrapper `c_derived::w` of `c::f2`, and pass the function pointer of `c_derived::f1` to `c::f2` from the wrapper `c_derived::w`.
Is there, instead, a reasonable way to do it?

Comment: It's c#, I know, but have you tried calling base.f1()?

Comment: Duplicate? Actually, Is this not the droid you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357307/how-to-call-a-parent-class-function-from-derived-class-function

Comment: @GrahamBass from the question, he wants to call the derived version from the base method. So just a simple call would do it...

Comment: That inversion of the numbers f was a little confusing, given the pattern established for class. Wouldn't this violate SOLID principles? Seems like a base class should not be aware of or dependent on derivatives?

Comment: Why is there a question in this question?  It reads to me like a complicated way of asking nothing.  For the simple meaning of the question, you just call f1().  That is how virtual functions work.  But if you implied a third class derived from `c_derived` and you don't want the normal action of virtual, you can directly call `c_derived::f1()`

Comment: @JSF it is a rigorous question to ask nothing for an OOP-trained programmer who frequently works with OOP, but to ask something relevant for a programmer which is not used to OOP who wants to get response to problems after showing thoughts and effort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the nice answer by Luchian Grigore, I'd like to point out that this idea is the one behind the [template method pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

That pattern let the derived classes decide how to complete an algorithm implementation, either by offering a default solution in the form of a virtual method or no solution at all by using a pure virtual method.

In both the cases above mentioned, the `f2` member invokes the right implementation of the `f1` member as it follows:

```
f1();
```

Knowing the name of the solution one is applying usually is helpful.

Answer (score 4):

This is tricky, but it can be done with some hacking:

```
void c::f2()
{
    f1();   // if f1 is overriden in a class deriving from c, 
            // the derived class version is called
}
```

To call base class version (`c::f1`), you need to fully qualify the call - `c::fi()`.