# C++: Calling a function from derived by a function pointer defined in base class

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

If a function pointer is defined and assigned values in base class. And it has to be used to call a function from a class derived from it. How can we do that?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485983/calling-c-class-methods-via-a-function-pointer) shows an example to call functions by pointers. But this works only in case when pointer is defined in same class from where it is being used.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357307/how-to-call-a-parent-class-function-from-derived-class-function) shows example to call parent class function. I tried some this similar but it didn't work.

```
From derived
(((Base)this)->*fncPtr)();
(((Base)this)->*(Base::fncPtr))();
```

Both of the above doesn't work. Please help me out.

Comment: You should better use the _Template Function Pattern_ than a function pointer for such cases.

Comment: Are you suggesting there is not solution for this. Apart from using Template Function Pattern?

Comment: I suggest that would be the better and more straightforward solution (and probably less error prone).

Comment: Okay Thanks. However, proceeding with that now will make me do a lot of change in the code base. Do you have any idea about solution for the above situation?

Comment: You'll need a pointer to the derived class object to call that function pointer correctly, so effectively you'll need to know the derived class type, that you can cast `this` to it. May be a template function (not to confuse with the mentioned _Template Function Pattern_) could be a viable solution.

Comment: Show some actual code and say _what_ didn't work, if you want help. Currently it's not at all clear what problem you're having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use:

```
(this->*fncPtr)();
```

Nothing else is required. Cast to base type is implicit. So you do not need to cast it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Given a pointer to member function of `Derived`:

```
void (Derived::*derivedFncPtr)() = &Derived::someMemberFunction;
```

First, cast it to a pointer to member function of `Base`:

```
void (Base::*baseFncPtr)() = static_cast<void (Base::*)()>(derivedFncPtr);
```

Then, call it: (assuming `*this` is a `Base` with dynamic type `Derived`)

```
(this->*baseFncPtr)();
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/WpaLcf)

Comment: Thanks. But here the pointer to member function is also of Base class.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Can you improve the question?

Comment: Done. Please see the example code again. I made some errors in the example code previously.

Comment: What happens when you try `(this->*fncPtr)()`?

Comment: I tried that but eclipse IDE was throwing error. Now after project clean it did work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a pointer to member function of base `void (Base::*fncPtr)()`, you can call it with a pointer to derived object `this` in exactly the same way as you would call a pointer to member function of that same derived class.

```
(this->*fncPtr)();
```

[Demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc3f9d62822a1196)

---

> ```
> (((Base)this)->*fncPtr)();
> ```

You can explicitly cast `this` to a pointer of `Base` if you really want to (it's not required), but this is not how it is done since `Base` is not a pointer type. This would work:

```
((Base*)this)->*fncPtr)();
```

But as I said, the cast is redundant.