# How stages are initialized in inet?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I have read the omnet and inet documentation but the initialization of stages is still unclear to me.
Will someone kindly explain how the stages are initialized in the following two lines? I am trying to understand example **testnewmac** in inet.

```
void EtherAppCli::initialize(int stage)
{ 
cSimpleModule::initialize(stage);
```

Comment: Maybe this related question can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357307/how-to-call-a-parent-class-function-from-derived-class-function