# Double Colon confusions

Tags: c++

Why can I use double colons in functions and classes not defined but I can't use in variables ??

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Person{

    public:
        int age;
        string name();
};

int Person::age = 10; //It outputs an error

string Person::name(){ //It doesn't
    return "n";
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this should work? I suggest you pick up a [_good_ book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: If you make age static then it will work.

Comment: Will it, @JerryJeremiah, or will it simply compile? Huge difference between works and compiles.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious maybe because I'm still learning?? I still have a very blind view on C ++.

Comment: @Dormin Meh, learning by guessing is not the way to go with C++, it's too weird for that. Really do read that C++ book.

Comment: @user4581301  static fields MUST be initialized outside the class - whether or not static is appropriate for any particular field is a different discussion...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why can I use double colons in functions and classes not defined but I can't use in variables ??

`age` is an **instance field**, it exists in multiple places in memory - one for each `Person` that exists.

I'll now expand in detail about what the `::` operator does, how to use it, and how `static` class members compare to instance members:

### The `::` operator:

The `::` (the [scope-resolution operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator)) has multiple uses in C++:

If you're familiar with Java, C# or JavaScript then it can be likened to the dot dereference or "navigation operator" `.` (e.g. `namespace.Class.Method().Result`) - except C++ uses a different operators for different kinds of navigation and dereferencing:

- `.` is the **member-access operator**, similar to C - it's only applicable for "object values" and references (`foo&`), not pointers (`foo*`).
- `->` is another **member-access operator** for pointer types, note that this operator *can* be overridden but `.` cannot (overridin `->` is risky but it improves the ergonomics of smart-pointer libraries when done correctly).
- `::` is the **scope-resolution operator** - it has a few different uses:

  - Namespace navigation - whereas Java and C# use `.` to navigate packages and namespaces, C++ uses `::`, for example: `using std::time`.
  - When unqualified, it's also used to reference the global namespace, e.g. `::std` which is handy if you're writing code which is already in a namespace.
  - It's also used to access static members of types - typically an actual `static` member (a static method or field) but also items like `enum class` (scoped enumeration) values (e.g. `SomeEnumClass::value_name`)
  - Finally, it's also used to select a specific base method when dealing with `virtual` method implementations: it's used when an overridden method needs to call a base implementation in a superclass - C++ does not have the singular `base` or `super` keywords that C# and Java have (respectively) because C++ allows multiple inheritance, so you must specify the specific parent class name: [How to call a parent class function from derived class function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357307/how-to-call-a-parent-class-function-from-derived-class-function)

Anyway, in your case, it looks like you're confused about what instance and static members actually mean, so here is an illustration:

```
class Person {
public:
    int height; // each Person has their own height, so this is an instance member
    static int averageHeight; // but an individual Person doesn't have an "average height" - but a single average-height value can be used for all Persons, so this is a shared ("static") value.

    int getAverageHeight() { // this is an instance method, btw
        return Person::averageHeight; // use `Person::` to unambiguously reference a static member of `Person`
    }

    Person()
    : height(0) {
        // instance members should be initialized in the constructor!
    }
}

// This will create an array of 10 people (10 different object instances).
// Each Person object (an instance) will have its own `height` in memory
Person* multiplePeople = new Person[10];

// btw, you probably should use `std::array` with an initializer instead:
// array<Person,10> multiplePeople{}; // <-- like this

// This sets a value to the `staticField` member, which exists only once in memory, that is, all Person instances share the same value for this member...
Person::averageHeight = 175; // 175cm

// ...for example:
assert( 175 == multiplePeople[3]->getAverageHeight() );
assert( 175 == multiplePeople[6]->getAverageHeight() );

// However instance members can have different values for each instance:
multiplePeople[3]->height = 170;
multiplePeople[6]->height = 180;

// Btw `height` is initialized to 0 in each Person's constructor.
assert( 170 != multiplePeople[0]->height );
assert( 180 != multiplePeople[7]->height );
```

Comment: @VladfromMoscow His question was about the background and use of the `::`operator - why do you think I didn't answer his question correctly?

Comment: @Dai The operator can be used also with non-static data members.

Comment: why use (raw!) Pointers explaining something like this to a beginner, why not use a vector of persons.