# How to properly overload the stream operator for printing in an polymorphic class?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, operator-overloading

EDIT: the code had a typo, now it compiles but I am still not getting the output I want.

I am attempting to overload the stream operator for `std::cout`, `std::fstream`, etc, but I am not being able to handle polymorphism properly: I am not able to get the output I want to see. 
I would like the subclasses to show the content of the superclass and then its content, while the superclass to show only its content.
This can be achieved by introducing a new function `print_only_base()` in the `Base` function, but I suspect that I can make the code working even without adding a new function.

**What I want to get**

I have a base class which has some attributes that I want to be showed on screen when I do

```
Base base;
std::cout << base;
```

There are two classes, `A` and `B` which inherits from `Base`. `Base` is a polymorphic class and `A` and `B` are showing different output when streamed.

I want an object of class `Base` to show only its output, while an object of class `A` (the same for `B`) to show first the output itself if seen as an instance of `Base` and then the output of itself seen as `A` (or `B`).

Below the code I write the output I would expect and my (not working) attempt.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
    virtual std::ostream & print(std::ostream stream) const {
        stream << "Base class output\n";
        return stream;
    }
public:
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & stream, const Base & obj) {
        return obj.print(stream);
    }
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class A : public Base {
    std::ostream & print(std::ostream & stream) const {
        stream << "foo = " << foo << "\n";
        return stream;
    }
    int foo = 0;
public:
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & stream, const A & obj) {
        // here I would like to call the base class for printing, but I would enter in an infinite loop
        return obj.print(stream);
    }
    ~A() {}
};

class B : public Base {
    std::ostream & print(std::ostream & stream) const {
        stream << "bar = " << bar << "\n";
        return stream;
    }
    int bar = 0;
public:
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & stream, const B & obj) {
        // here I would like to call the base class for printing, but I would enter in an infinite loop
        return obj.print(stream);
    }
    ~B() {}
};
```

Main function:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    Base * base = new Base();
    A * a = new A();
    B * b = new B();
    Base * a_inside = dynamic_cast<Base *>(a);

    std::cout << *base << "\n";
    std::cout << *a << "\n";
    std::cout << *b << "\n";
    std::cout << *a_inside << "\n";

    delete base;
    delete a;
    delete b;

    /* output I want to get
       Base class output

       Base class output
       foo = 0

       Base class output
       bar = 0

       Base class output
       foo = 0
    */


    return 0;
}
```

How can I get the desired behaviour?

Comment: Did you try passing `std::ostream` by reference?

Comment: Uh, that is only a typo fortunately! The compiler error is gone, but still I am not getting the desired output (see the last comment on the code for classes)

Comment: Then it is a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357307/how-to-call-a-parent-class-function-from-derived-class-function).  You need `return Base::print(stream)`

Comment: @NathanOliver I added this `return obj.Base::print(stream);` and made `print` protected in the base class, but I am not getting the correct output.

Comment: I've retracted my close vote.  You'll need more changes as pointed out in the answer below.

Comment: Remove `friend std::ostream & operator<<` in the derived classes, IMO the base class's overload should be able to handle the derived ones too.  Then in the overridden `print()` methods, call `Base::print()` first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is very simple.

1. Define the `operator<<` function only for the base class. There is no need to define it for the derived types.
2. Rely on the `virtual` function mechanism to invoke the `print` function of the derived class.
3. Add code to call `Base::print` from the derived classes before printing the derived class specific content. Make sure the function is not `private` in the base class.

---

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
   protected:
      virtual std::ostream & print(std::ostream& stream) const {
         stream << "Base class output\n";
         return stream;
      }

   public:

   // Define it only for the base class.
   friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & stream, const Base & obj) {
      return obj.print(stream);
   }

   virtual ~Base() {}
};

class A : public Base {

   std::ostream & print(std::ostream & stream) const {
      // Print the base class specific information first.
      Base::print(stream);

      // Print the derived class specific information.
      stream << "foo = " << foo << "\n";
      return stream;
   }

   int foo = 0;
   public:
   ~A() {}
};

class B : public Base {

   std::ostream & print(std::ostream & stream) const {
      // Print the base class-specific information first.
      Base::print(stream);

      // Print the derived class specific information.
      stream << "bar = " << bar << "\n";
      return stream;
   }

   int bar = 0;
   public:
   ~B() {}
};
```

With those changes, I get the desired output. See it working at https://ideone.com/x6ti3W.

Comment: Working great, thanks! I think that the return value of print is redundant, I can make it void, call `obj.print(stream)` in `Base` and then return `stream`.

Comment: `this->` before `Base::print` can be removed.

Comment: @Nisba, you're welcome. Yes, you can change the return type of `print` to `void` without affecting the functionality.