# Inheritance, overriding, and virtual functions to avoid repeated code

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I have three classes, A, B, and C. B and C are derived from A. Both B and C need to implement a method `F`. The code in B.F() is a subset of C.F().

1. Is it a good way declare `A.F()` as a virtual function and define `B.F()` and `C.F()`? There would be the same code in 2 methods, which I would like to avoid. What are the other 
   possibilities?
2. Define `A.F()` with the common code and override it in `C.F()`. While overriding how can the output of A.F() be used in C.F(), so that repeated code can be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I guess it's not the best thing to do. If you can avoid code rewriting - sure, do it.
2. It would be better to define `F()` in `A`, as you've said, with the common code for both `B` and `C`, and then override it in `C.F()`, using `A::F()` call in overriden function. I mean, with this you can firstly execute parent method `A.F()`, and then go with new extra logic. If you're inheriting `B` from `A`, you shouldn't then bother about this method in `B` at all.

Note that from this point of view, the order will be important. If you want parent code execution to be first, then call `A::F()` before your additional logic. It's on you to decide, what order to choose, though.

EDIT

I will add a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357307/how-to-call-a-parent-class-function-from-derived-class-function) with a good example for you, if you don't know how to call parent method code inside child method. Take a look, and have a nice time.