How can I avoid calling a static function (and call a base member function instead)?
I have a static instance (previously called singleton, but commenters were taking issue with that) of a class which derives from a base class. So far, so good.
Derived has a static function fun, while Base has a member function fun (don't ask). Obviously, calling instance->fun() in Derived::fun() creates an infinite recursion ending in a stack overflow.
I managed to avoid that by calling ((Base*)instance)->fun() instead:
struct Base {
    void fun() { /* ... */ }
};

struct Derived;

static Derived * instance = nullptr;

struct Derived : Base {
    static void fun() {
        // stack overflow!
        // instance->fun();

        // works!
        ((Base*)instance)->fun();
    }
};

int main() {
    instance = new Derived();
    Derived::fun();
}

Is there a better way to avoid calling the static function defined in Derived?

Future readers take heed: This is probably the result of the code being [mre]-ed all to hell to simplify the question, but the presented code does not implement a singleton.  A modern singleton will look more like this.

The static doesn't really affect anything here; the same problem would occur with a non-static member function. The issue is name lookup.

why do you think you need something better ?

"I have a singleton"  You don't here.  Choosing to create one of something doesn't make it a singleton.

@DrewDormann -- this is obviously a distillation of the problem, not a verbatim reproduction. That's how it's supposed to be.

If you are asking on how to call base class method with the same signature as a method of the derived class, here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/357380/19871088

@PeteBecker wouldn't an obvious distillation of this problem have no singletons?  This isn't a question about singletons.  I see a misunderstanding of terminology, but perhaps I am wrong.

@DrewDormann -- obviously the original code used a singleton, and the distillation removed everything that makes it a singleton except for the name of the pointer. One of the worst features of Stackoverflow is people who insist on their version of precision despite a question being perfectly clear. Just pretend that there is no mention of "singleton" and you'll probably understand the question better.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai gut feeling. In fact, I always wonder if there is something better, even if I do not have a specific reason to do so. And looking at Eugene's answer, I feel my gut feeling was right.

"Just pretend that there is no mention of "singleton" and you'll probably understand the question better." - @PeteBecker nailed it. I removed the term "singleton" from the question, naming the variable instance instead.

You can call the function instance->Base::fun().
