# How do I call an overridden parent class method from a child class?

Tags: java, inheritance

If I have a subclass that has methods I've overridden from the parent class, and under very specific situations I want to use the original methods, how do I call those methods?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, how to I call a base class's method from the overriding method in a derived class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268929/in-java-how-to-i-call-a-base-classs-method-from-the-overriding-method-in-a-deri)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

call super

```
class A {
   int foo () { return 2; }
}

class B extends A {

   boolean someCondition;

   public B(boolean b) { someCondition = b; }

   int foo () { 
       if(someCondition) return super.foo();
       return 3;
   }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't foo() method in Class A be static so that you can call it like: super.foo() ?

Comment: @Eng Nope! static means something very different.

Answer (score 6):

That's what `super` is for. If you override method `method`, then you might implement it like this:

```
protected void method() {
    if (special_conditions()) {
        super.method();
    } else {
        // do your thing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can generally use the keyword `super` to access the parent class's function.
for example:

```
public class Subclass extends Superclass {

    public void printMethod() { //overrides printMethod in Superclass
        super.printMethod();
        System.out.println("Printed in Subclass");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Subclass s = new Subclass();
    s.printMethod();    
    }

}
```

Taken from http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html