# if there are two methods with same name in Parent class and Child Class ..?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

If there are two methods with same name in Parent class and Child Class, for example:

Parent class:

```
public abstract class Employee implements Payments {
    private String name;
    protected double basicSalary;

    public Employee(String name, double basicSalary) {
        this.basicSalary = basicSalary;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println( " Name: " + name + " - Basic Salary: " + basicSalary +"SR" );
    }
}
```

Child class:

```
public class Faculty extends Employee {
    private String degree;
    private int teachingHours;

    public Faculty(String name, double salary, String degree, int teachingHours) {
        super(name, salary);
        this.degree = degree;
        this.teachingHours = teachingHours;
    }   

    public void display() {
        System.out.println( " Name: " +getName() + " - Degree:" +degree);
    }
```

And I create an object like this:

```
Employee[] arrEm = new Employee[4];
arrEm[0] = new Faculty("ahmad", 1000, "Phd", 10);
```

So if I write

```
arrEm[0].display();
```

this way the method `display()` will be used in child. But in case we want to use the method display in Parent Class, how can it be done?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: **java !== javascript**

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268929/in-java-how-do-i-call-a-base-classs-method-from-the-overriding-method-in-a-der

Comment: Javascript tag deleted

Comment: Please put in the effort to post well-formatted and compilable code.

Comment: Read Overriding and polymorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because first you do: 
`Employee [] arrEm = new Employee [4];`
this will make arrEm array for objects. Then you do this:
`arrEm[0]= new Faculty("ahmad" , 1000 , "Phd" , 10 );`
You use the arrEm[0] to refer a child class object so it will use display of the child. This is a normal case of polymorphism. You can search for it on google. It's useful. If you want to use the parent display use

```
arrEm[0] = new Employee;
```

or there is a way to upcast like

```
child a= new child();
```

Parent p=(Parent)a;

this a.display() will use the display in the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call it as the following :

```
super.display();
```

Comment: sorry i dont understand yet .. I try write " arrEm[0].super.dislay(); "
he give me an error and if i write " super.display(); "  i dont selecte the object so how java will know i mean this arrEm[0] or arrEm[1] ? and i try write "   super.dislay(); "  in main class he give me error

Answer (score 0):

Then either don't declare display method in child class or create instance of parent class instead of child class like`rrEm[0]= new Employee("ahmad" , 1000  )`(though i don't think you want this)or call parent method from child class like `super.display()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call display method of parent class, you should add super.dislay() to display() method of Faculty class.

```
public class Faculty extends Employee {
private String degree;
private int teachingHours;

public Faculty( String name , double salary , String degree , int teachingHours) 
{
    super(name , salary );
    this.degree=degree;
    this.teachingHours = teachingHours;
}   
public void display()
{
    //calling display() method of parent class
    Super.display();
    System.out.println( " Name: " +getName() + " - Degree:" +degree);
}
```

or
If you do not want to call it from child class then create object using parent class constructor not child class.

```
  Employee [] arrEm = new Employee [4];
  //calling parent class constructor
  arrEm[0]= new Employee("ahmad");
```

Here you can not make use of members of Faculty class(degree, teachingHours).